# python program raising exceptions

Tags: python, exception, raise

Im working on a finger exercise from Guttag Intro to computer science and programming using python, and Im working on the following finger exercise:

Finger Exercise: Implement a function that satisfies the specification
def findAnEven(l):
"""Assumes l is a list of integers
Returns the first even number in l
Raises ValueError if l does not contain an even number"""

This is what I wrote so far, it get's the job done, but is definitely not what Guttag intended as an answer.

```
   def isEven(l):
        """Assumes l is a list of integars
           returns the first even number in list
           raises an exception if no even number in list"""
        for i in l:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                print i, " is the first even number in the list"            
                exit()
        raise ValueError("No even numbers in list!")
```

I would highly appreciate any input on how professor Guttag intended the code to look. I'm assuming I should have used the try statement somewhere, and the using the exit statement is very crude in this context. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you ask him directly?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't look the way he wants? It **does** what he wants, right?

Comment: Not in MIT, just using the book. It does what he wants, but I feel I should have used a try statement and a while loop somehow.

Comment: One of the python things they never teach you: you can manually `break` out of loops (common knowledge), **and** you can have an `else` clause to a `for` loop, which executes if the loop was not broken (this is the sneaky part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is the usage of `exit()`. Generally `return` will exit for you. To fix the code, just remove it:

```
def isEven(l): 
        for i in l: 
                if i % 2 == 0: 
                        return i 
        raise ValueError("No even numbers in list!")
```

Comment: thank you, I guess it just looks sloppy. I think I should've used a try statement and a while loop somehow. Thanks anyway

Comment: no, it doesn't look sloppy; it's just that this is how Python looks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this by using the try-except:

```
def findEven(L):
    try:
        for num in L: 
            if num%2==0:
                return num
        else:
            num/0
    except:
        raise ValueError
```

To enter the except block, there needs to be an error in the try block. I intently added a Zero division operation in the try block to get it to produce the ZeroDivisionError in case no even number was found. This error allows the exception block to execute. Hope it helps someone else in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on this part. This is my code:

```
def findEven(L):
    try:
        for num in L: 
            if num%2==0:
            return num
            else:
                num/0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("No even numbers in list!")
    except:
        raise ValueError("findEven called with bad arguments")
```

I found that if I didn't use `ZeroDivisionError`,the IDLE Shell will show `ZeroDivisionError` first, and then show this line

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```